# Parent fragment's onCreateView is called after child fragments onCreateView

Tags: android, fragment, parent-child, fragment-oncreateview

I have a `ParentFragment` and a `ChildFragment` that extends from it. I placed a log in `onCreateView` method of both fragments. But `ParentFragment`'s `onCreateView` is being called last.

However, the same parent-child relationship between activities is producing the expected result. Parent activities `onCreate` is being called first and then child activity's `onCreate`.

`ParentFragment`

```
abstract class ParentFragment<T: ViewDataBinding>: Fragment(){

    @LayoutRes
    abstract fun getLayoutResId(): Int

    protected lateinit var binding: T


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        Log.d("-----------", "onCreateView ParentFragment")
        return DataBindingUtil.inflate<T>(inflater, getLayoutResId(), container, false).apply { binding = this }.root
    }
```

`ChildFragment`

```
class ChildFragment: ParentFragment<FragmentChildBinding>() {

    @LayoutRes
    override fun getLayoutResId() = R.layout.fragment_child

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.d("-----------", "onCreateView ChildFragment")

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false)
    }
```

Result for Fragments:

```
2019-12-10 10:54:28.054 32450-32450/blabla.yeahyeah D/-----------: onCreateView ChildFragment
2019-12-10 10:54:28.054 32450-32450/blabla.yeahyeah D/-----------: onCreateView ParentFragment
```

Result for Activities:

```
2019-12-10 10:54:27.796 32450-32450/blabla.yeahyeah D/-----------: onCreate ParentActivity
2019-12-10 10:54:27.931 32450-32450/blabla.yeahyeah D/-----------: onCreate ChildActivity
```

Can you please help with this? Am I missing something or is it an expected behavior?

The reason why I am overriding `onCreateView` is that I am trying to connect my `viewModel` to my `binding` in `ChildFragment` like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.d("-----------", "onCreateView ChildFragment")

        val viewModel = getViewModel()
        binding.viewModel = viewModel //CRASH HAPPENING HERE. THIS VARIABLE IS NOT INITIALIZED
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        return binding.root
    }
```

Currently, I am getting crash becuse `binding` variable is not initialized when I access it from `ChildFragment`. Since this variable needs to be initialized in `ParentFragment` and `ParentFragment` is being called after `ChildFragment`, I amgetting crash as I understood.

Comment: Why do you override `onCreateView()` in child fragment anyway? You're already doing data binding in parent's `onCreateView()`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede explained why I am doing this. Check out the question again please.

Comment: Try your initialization in `onViewCreated()` method, it's subsequent call after `onCreateView()`, in this method your binding object would not be null.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Yes it helped. Thanks. How can I optimize my code so that I do not need to write this boilerplate code in every child fragment?

Comment: Your structure seems pretty strait forward to me. Just make sure that any code common to all fragments relies on parent fragment rather than all of child. Just let me know what are other boilerplate code!

Comment: @JeelVankhede well I had some issues with that. Could you please have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279430/optimizing-parent-fragment-for-viewmodel-and-databinding-in-order-to-avoid-boile